# import csv file with data to mysql

Tags: mysql, database, csv

I'm trying to import csv file to MYSQL, and I have the following schema.

```
CREATE TABLE `monitor` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`time` time DEFAULT NULL,
`domain_name` text,
`cpu_ns` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`cpu_percentage` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`mem_bytes` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`mem_percentage` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`block_rdby` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`block_wrby` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`net_rxby` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`net_wrby` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I'm having issues importing a file with data presented as follows.

```
16:48:27,2,s-1-VM,220000000.,0.448204684384,262144,0,0,0,60,0
16:48:30,2,s-1-VM,260000000.,0.528932926209,262144,0,0,16384,300,0
16:48:33,2,s-1-VM,300000000.,0.609786677944,262144,0,0,0,180,0
16:48:37,2,s-1-VM,290000000.,0.59000206364,262144,0,0,16384,120,0
16:48:40,2,s-1-VM,270000000.,0.54985661784,262144,0,0,0,649,425
16:48:43,2,s-1-VM,310000000.,0.631207212346,262144,0,0,0,180,0
16:48:46,2,s-1-VM,220000000.,0.44728232907,262144,0,0,20480,60,0
16:48:49,2,s-1-VM,200000000.,0.407008216196,262144,0,0,0,300,0
16:48:52,2,s-1-VM,250000000.,0.508946559213,262144,0,0,0,240,0
16:48:55,2,s-1-VM,240000000.,0.488674160215,262144,0,0,0,120,0
```

How can import this to my database?

I have tried the following and I get lots of warnings.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/domain2.csv' INTO TABLE vtop  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

your help is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/load-data.html correctly, you should set ID to null (that makes it auto_increment) via

```
"SET id=NULL "
```

at the end of the statement. Otherwise column counts and column orders have to match perfectly.

But your columns don't match at all (what is the "2" at position 2?). So create a temp-Table with the structure of your CSV and then assign via insert into ... select the matching columns.

Comment: I have not yet known the possibility to list the column names as given in the other answers, just be careful with the strange second column and if it is not needed in the table then put it in a variable like <at>dummy1, as in (time, @dummy1, domain_name, cpu_ns...)

Comment: You were right about the ID, and about the mistake in the columns and schema! a big thank you to you!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL isn't an AI and can't figure out that `16:48:27` should go into the the `time` field - it'll be trying to stuff that into `id` instead.

You need to explictly map the columns in your CSV file to the fields they should go into in the table:

```
LOAD DATA .... (time, domain_name, x, y, z, foo, bar)
```